# JUnit test runs out of memory -- how to increase heap size?

Tags: java, netbeans, junit, heap-size

I am running a Junit test which throws an exception OutOfMemory.
The test is started *inside* NetBeans 6.9.X. When profiling it I've
realized that the Heap maxSize is 64M. I would like to increment this 
but I couldn't find how to do this.

I already tried right click at the project ->properties ->Run
and under the VM options I've set -Xms300M but this didn't work.

Any hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try changing/adding the Xms parameter netbeans_default_options in etc/netbeans.conf

Comment: Thanks, already tried and it is not working. It crashes when the heap reaches 64M. I've set this netbeans_default_options = "-J-Xms384m -J-Xmx512m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=96m -J-Xverify:none -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemory"

Comment: Post your stack trace please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/NetBeans_Tips#How_to_increase_Heap_Size_for_JUnit_test

Edit your project.properties file and add the line:

```
test.run.args=-Xms128m -Xmx1400m
```

Comment: Unfortunately that link is broken now.

Comment: Here's an archived version of that page:

http://web.archive.org/web/20130314101004/http://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/NetBeans_Tips

Comment: Does that still apply to Netbeans 8?  Current Netbeans doc has no reference to that file that I could find, and if I put it in the prescribed place, nothing happens, the test still runs with default memory.

Answer (score 5):

You can also increase the max size for all VMs by setting this environment variable for your OS:

```
 _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx300m
```

Comment: I didn't know that.  Thats cool.    So, on windows you could do:  SET /P _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx300M ?  Awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Have you adjusted -Xmx as well as -Xms

-Xms300m will force java using no less 300m, and -Xmx300m will let jvm use no more than 300m

Answer (score 1):

You can try this and see if it helps:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

Comment: No. This is not about permgen. He is running out of total heap.

Comment: No, thats incorrect.  He didn't he ran out of heap.  He said "OutOfMemory" (in general) and I know that the PermGen argument fixes a certain type of OOME.

Comment: True. I am curious though to know why you think this this not a total heap problem but rather specifically permgen problem.

Answer (score 0):

While Java program usually don't leak memory in usual sense there could be memory unnecessarily occupied in collections like lists and maps. Use a profiler to see where the memory is being used, you will likely find opportunities for optimization.